# Laravel how to change objects

Tags: php, laravel

this is some of my code in laravel, i have array of object that name results, i want to insert each result a social media account.. how to fix it?

```
    $results = Buzzer::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'buzzers.user_id')->get();
    $buzz[] = "";
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $sosmeds = SocialMedia::where('user_id','=',$result->user_id)->get();
        foreach ($sosmeds as $sosmed) {
            if($sosmed->type == "facebook") $result['facebook'] = $sosmed;
            if($sosmed->type == "twitter") $result['twitter'] = $sosmed;
            if($sosmed->type == "instagram") $result['instagram'] = $sosmed;
        }
        $buzz[] = $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if i understand your question.
You can add new data in each object by inserting new index inside your loop.

```
$result->you_index = "your value";
```

In your case, You should do this :

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $sosmeds = SocialMedia::where('user_id','=',$result->user_id)->get();
    foreach ($sosmeds as $sosmed) {
        if($sosmed->type == "facebook") $result->facebook = $sosmed;
        if($sosmed->type == "twitter") $result->twitter = $sosmed;
        if($sosmed->type == "instagram") $result->instagram = $sosmed;
    }
}
```